# ??? Error using ==> plot - conversion to double from sym is not possible

Tags: plot, matlab

I'm having some problems with my code. Here it is:

```
lambdaz = 1.2;
n = 24;
mu = 0.00055e9;

lambda = sym('lambda','clear');
W = (((2.*mu)./n.^2)).*((lambda.^n)+(lambdaz.^n)+((lambda.^-n).*(lambdaz.^-n))-3);
dW_dlambda = diff(W, lambda);

W2=(((2.*mu)./n.^2).*(lambda.^n))+(((2.*mu)./n.^2).*(lambdaz.^n))+(((2.*mu)./n.^2).*((lambda.^-n).*(lambdaz.^-n)))-(3.*((2.*mu)./n.^2))
dW2_dlambda=diff(W2,lambda)

x=((((lambda.^2).*(lambdaz))-1).^-1).*(dW_dlambda);

x2=((((lambda.^2).*(lambdaz))-1).^-1).*(dW2_dlambda)

P2 = int(x2,lambda)

P=int(x,lambda);
P=(0:1000:26700)

plot(lambda,P)
```

When I try to plot lambda against P I get the "conversion to double from sym is not possible" error message. I'm not particularly fantastic at Matlab so any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Is this R? If so, you should tag it so.

Answer (score 1):

The `plot` function only works for numeric inputs. Both `lambda` and `P` are symbolic expressions (at least before overwrote `P` by setting it equal to a vector after the integration) that cannot be directly converted to to floating point. You get the same error if try to something like `double(sym('exp(x)'))`. You have two options. The first is the [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezplot.html) function in the Symbolic Toolbox:

```
...
P = int(x,lambda);
ezplot(P,[-5 5]); % Plot's P from lambda = -5 to lambda = 5
```

Or you can use the [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) function:

```
...
P = int(x,lambda);
lambda = -5:0.01:5;
plot(lambda,real(subs(P,'lambda',lambda)))
axis([lambda(1) lambda(end) -1e15 1e15])
```

I used `real` to suppress a warning for negative values of `lambda`.